# What's the difference between the capistrano-rvm and rvm1-capistrano3 gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, capistrano, rvm-capistrano

In Capistrano 3 I'm confused which gem I should use to install RVM and Ruby on my server.

There's [capistrano-rvm](https://github.com/capistrano/rvm) and [rvm1-capistrano3](https://github.com/rvm/rvm1-capistrano3). To make matters more confusing, [there's a commit in capistrano-rvm](https://github.com/capistrano/rvm/pull/34) saying it's merged both projects.

I tried with the earlier, and I could not get it to work. Additionally, its docs say it can't "install Rubys".

So what's going on? Are they meant to do the same thing? Why have two gems?